# Expand AD groups recursively in f#

Tags: f#, active-directory

I'm writing a f# script to check if a [System.DirectoryServices.Principal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal(v=vs.110).aspx) object is a group or a user. If its a group I have to get the list of users in the group recursively and if its a user return the user as a list. I wrote the following function

```
let rec getUserlist (p:Principal) = 
    match box p with 
        | :? UserPrincipal as u -> [u:>Principal]
        | :? GroupPrincipal as g when g.IsSecurityGroup.HasValue && g.IsSecurityGroup.Value 
            -> g.GetMembers(false).ToArray() 
            |> Seq.map(fun p -> getUserlist p) 
            |> Seq.concat
            |> Seq.toList
        | _ -> []
```

This function works but it doesn't look very clean to me. I was wondering if there was a better way to write this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to box it to pattern match over the type and it makes no sense to use the downcasted variable `u` only to upcast it again.

Also note that `map` then `concat` is `collect` and you are transforming to array, then to list ... better use `seq` and once you get all the results transform it to whatever you want at the call site.

```
let rec getUserlist (p:Principal) = 
    match p with 
        | :? UserPrincipal -> Seq.singleton p
        | :? GroupPrincipal as g when g.IsSecurityGroup.HasValue && g.IsSecurityGroup.Value 
            -> g.GetMembers false |> Seq.collect getUserlist
        | _ -> Seq.empty
```

if you prefer you can use sequence expressions:

```
let rec getUserlist (p:Principal) = seq {
    match p with 
        | :? UserPrincipal as u -> yield p
        | :? GroupPrincipal as g when g.IsSecurityGroup.HasValue && g.IsSecurityGroup.Value 
            -> for p in g.GetMembers false do
                    yield! getUserlist p
        | _ -> ()}
```